# Finding which of 4 scores reach a certain amount first

Tags: python, tkinter, game-engine

I am trying to find who wins in my game, and then, as well as printing all the player's scores, say who won. However, I've not been doing Python long and I have no idea how to. Here is the relevant parts of the code:

```
w = 19 #When any of the scores reach more than 19, the game ends.
x = 19
y = 19
z = 19

while gamealive ==1:
    if ball.score1 > w or ball.score2 > x or ball.score3 > y or ball.score4 > z:
        gamealive=0 # stops the game trying to redraw everything
        canvas.delete(ALL) #clears the canvas
        canvas.create_text(350, 160, font=("Bauhaus 93",30), fill = 'Red', text='Game Over') #Puts Text on Canvas OGBP
        txtpad1score = canvas.create_text(440, 350, font=("Bauhaus 93",40), fill = 'white', text='0') #Puts scores on end canvas
        txtpad2score = canvas.create_text(440, 400, font=("Bauhaus 93",40), fill = 'white', text='0') 
        txtpad3score = canvas.create_text(440, 450, font=("Bauhaus 93",40), fill = 'white', text='0') 
        txtpad4score = canvas.create_text(440, 500, font=("Bauhaus 93",40), fill = 'white', text='0')

    canvas.itemconfig(txtpad1score,text = str(ball.score1))
    canvas.itemconfig(txtpad2score,text = str(ball.score2))
    canvas.itemconfig(txtpad3score,text = str(ball.score3))
    canvas.itemconfig(txtpad4score,text = str(ball.score4))

    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.001)
```

I want to have it so that when one of the scores reaches 19 or above, the game ends and prints each player's scores. This works, but I also want it so that it says 'Player 1 (or whichever player got above 19 first) wins!' but I don't know how to get the program to show which one of the scores reached 19 or more first. So if player 3, or txtpad3score, reaches 20, I want it to say 'Player 3 wins!'. Any help would be great.

Comment: Will you only ever have one winner? What have you tried so far? How about an `if`?

Comment: There will only ever be one winner. It is impossible for two players' scores to go up at the same time. Haven't tried anything anywhere near slightly successful so far.

Comment: Ah fixed it, your 'how about an if' helped a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only one player can have a score of 19 or more, you can just test the scores in a regular `if` statement.

```
winmesssage = canvas.create_text(440, 550, font=("Bauhaus 93",40), fill = 'white', text='0')

winner = ''
if score1 >= 19:
    winner = '1'
elif score2 >= 19:
    winner = '2'
elif score3 >= 19:
    winner = '3'
elif score4 >= 19:
    winner = '4'

message = 'Player {0} wins!'.format(winner)

canvas.itemconfig(winmessage,text = message)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if ball.score1 > w or ball.score2 > x or ball.score3 > y or ball.score4 > z:
        gamealive=0 # stops the game trying to redraw everything
        canvas.delete(ALL) # delete all 
        canvas.create_text(350, 160, font=("Bauhaus 93",30), fill = 'Red', text='Game Over') 
        txtpad1score = canvas.create_text(440, 350, font=("Bauhaus 93",40), fill = 'white', text='0') 
        txtpad2score = canvas.create_text(440, 400, font=("Bauhaus 93",40), fill = 'white', text='0') 
        txtpad3score = canvas.create_text(440, 450, font=("Bauhaus 93",40), fill = 'white', text='0') 
        txtpad4score = canvas.create_text(440, 500, font=("Bauhaus 93",40), fill = 'white', text='0') 
        canvas.create_text(260, 350, font = ('Bauhaus 93', 40), fill = 'white', text = 'Orange Score:')
        canvas.create_text(260, 400, font = ('Bauhaus 93', 40), fill = 'white', text = 'Green Score:')
        canvas.create_text(260, 450, font = ('Bauhaus 93', 40), fill = 'white', text = 'Blue Score:')
        canvas.create_text(260, 500, font = ('Bauhaus 93', 40), fill = 'white', text = 'Purple Score:')
        if ball.score1 > w:
            canvas.create_text(350, 600, font = ('Bauhaus 93', 40), fill = 'white', text = 'Orange wins!')
        if ball.score2 > x:
            canvas.create_text(350, 600, font = ('Bauhaus 93', 40), fill = 'white', text = 'Green wins!')
        if ball.score3 > y:
            canvas.create_text(350, 600, font = ('Bauhaus 93', 40), fill = 'white', text = 'Blue wins!')
        if ball.score4 > z:
            canvas.create_text(350, 600, font = ('Bauhaus 93', 40), fill = 'white', text = 'Purple wins!')
```